# change clock's precision

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clock

Env: Win Xp, Visual C++

I use clock() to measure the time cost in my program.
But the t_clock always be the multiply of 10, for example 10, 20, 30,
40,...
And I want to get the precision of 1, such as 11, 12, 13, 14...
How can I change the t_clock's precision?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't; clock() uses the system's ordinary RTC. What you actually need to use are High Performance Timers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx

Comment: Yesss...thanks a lot..that's exacly w'r I need

Answer (score 1):

Use the timeBeginPeriod API call to increase resolution to 1ms.